# Running CLI php script with execute bit

Tags: php, linux, command-line

This has been bugging me slightly.

I know you can do

```
php foo.php
```

or

```
php -f foo.php
```

Is there no way to just launch a script with the execute bit set

```
./foo.php
```

Given the folowing:

```
#!/usr/bin/php

<?php 
exit('hello');
```

I get "Could not open input file" or " bad interpreter: No such file or directory" depending on if there's whitespace after "bin/php".

Comment: do you have php in /usr/bin/php?

Comment: @Subdigger Yup. Does this work for you? I'm not sure if I'm trying to force it to do something it's not meant to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The example code you've given seems OK and works for me (I added the the closing `?>` though)

If you can run the file with `/usr/bin/php foo.php` there's something weird going on. Just a wild guess, but maybe you text editor leaves a BOM (byte order mark) at the beginning of the file, so that the `#!` aren't the very first two bytes in that file. (you can find out by doing `hexdump -C foo.php | head`)

Answer (score 7):

Instead of `#!/usr/bin/php`, using `#!/usr/bin/env php` is a better solution. This will look up the PHP binary in the `PATH` environment variable. This is *much* more robust & crossplatform. BSD for example installs PHP in `/usr/local/bin/php`.

Further, you will need to make sure this is the **first** line, and that the script has the executable bit set, to set it for everyone (Generally OK) use: `chmod a+x script.php`

Also make sure you have the CLI SAPI enabled. Run `php -v` top verify, it should show something like:

```
[~]% php -v
PHP 5.3.3 (cli) (built: Jul 22 2010 16:21:30)
Copyright (c) 1997-2010 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Zend Technologies
```

Answer (score 5):

1. Check if you have nothing before '#!', like an UTF-8 BOM
2. Check if you don't have anything at the end of the line, like CR (\r) befor the final LF (\n). The CR goes there if you write the file in Windows with windows line endings (CR LF) and may be interpreted as a part of the interpreter path.

Answer (score 2):

From the `php(1)` manpage:

> **TIPS**
>
> You can use a shebang line to automatically invoke php from
>   scripts. Only the CLI version of PHP will ignore such a first line as
>   shown below:
>
> ```
> #!/bin/php
> <?php
> // your script
> ?>
> ```

So, the shebang method does work. I'm getting ": No such file or directory" if I set line endings to something other than "unix" in Vim. Are you using DOS line endings in your script?